# How to assign range type bounds using multiple attributes in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a PostgreSQL range column called 'time_range'.

```
CREATE table my_table (
    time_range tstzrange
);
```

I would like to expose this as two columns 'earliest' and 'latest', defined as the lower() and upper() of the range value respectively.

It seems that I can use [hybrid](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html#using-a-hybrid) or [column_property](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html#using-column-property) to split the range value into multiple attributes for reading:

```
from sqlalchemy Column, func
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import column_property

Base = declarative_base()

class MyClass(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'
    earliest = column_property(func.lower(Column('time_range', postgresql.TSTZRANGE())))
    latest = column_property(func.upper(Column('time_range', postgresql.TSTZRANGE())))
```

Is there a way to define the reverse for writing to the DB?

ie. Is there a way to define the class so that the range column's value is produced from the 'earliest' and 'latest' attributes when writing the object back to the DB?

The consumer/user would then do something like:

```
instance = session.query(MyClass).first()
instance.earliest_timestamp = now
instance.latest_timestamp = now + timedelta(hours=2)
session.commit() 
# The value of the time_range column in the DB should be tstzrange(now, now+2hours)
```